# What causes the error: The "NgenLocalized" parameter is not supported

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-extensions

My project is a Visual Studio Extension. The solution contains multiple projects and references multiple NuGet packages.

On building the solution, I am getting the two errors:

> error MSB4064: The "NgenLocalized" parameter is not supported by the
>   "GenerateFileManifest" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task,
>   and it is a settable public instance property.
>
> error MSB4063: The "GenerateFileManifest" task could not be
>   initialized with its input parameters.

The complete errors are:

```
C:\Users\Phil\.nuget\packages\microsoft.vssdk.buildtools\16.3.2093\tools\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets(685,88): error MSB4064: The "NgenLocalized" parameter is not supported by the "GenerateFileManifest" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
C:\Users\Phil\.nuget\packages\microsoft.vssdk.buildtools\16.3.2093\tools\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets(685,5): error MSB4063: The "GenerateFileManifest" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
```

I get these errors build a release or a debug build.

**What do these error mean and how can I get rid of them?**

---

Strangely, if I simply start debugging, it builds without the errors and starts visual studio. However, in that case, I cannot load my package.

The activity log shows the error:

```
SetSite failed for package [MultiLanguagePackage]
Source: "MultiLanguageWPF" 
Description: Method not found: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.get_JoinableTaskFactory()".
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.get_JoinableTaskFactory()".
   at MultiLanguageWPF.MultiLanguagePackage.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&amp; stateMachine)
   at MultiLanguageWPF.MultiLanguagePackage.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress`1 progress)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass19_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()</description>
```

That might be a related error, or it might not be.

Comment: Try using another version of the nuget package. Maybe this issue results from that.

Comment: Just for information. The runtime error "SetSite failed for package" is a different error, but slightly related. I had added a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading 6.3.13 in order to resolve a conflict. After downgrading Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools to 16.2.3073 I was also able to remove the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading (without generating a conflict) and the "SetSite failed" error also went away.

Comment: Useful info, Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error MSB4064: The "NgenLocalized" parameter is not supported by the
> "GenerateFileManifest" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task,
> and it is a settable public instance property.
>
> error MSB4063: The "GenerateFileManifest" task could not be
> initialized with its input parameters.

Can't reproduce exactly same issue in my machine cause I lack the necessary enough info about your project. But I guess maybe this's one issue about the `Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools` package with `16.3.2093` version.

**Some tests and discovery:**

Msbuild use targets to manage the build process. We can consider [msbuild target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019) as the group of [msbuild tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-tasks?view=vs-2019). The task is a unit of executable code used by MSBuild to perform atomic build operations.

I opened the `Microsoft.VsSDK.targets`(version ) file at line 685 and found content below:

```
  <Target Name="GenerateFileManifest"
          Outputs="$(FileManifest)"
          DependsOnTargets="$(GenerateFileManifestDependsOn)">
    <GenerateFileManifest FileItems="@(VsixSourceItem)" FileManifest="$(FileManifest)" NgenLocalized="$(NgenLocalized)">
      <Output TaskParameter="FileManifest" ItemName="FileWrites" />
    </GenerateFileManifest>
  </Target>
```

So it's obvious during build process of your vsix project, it will call `GenerateFileManifest` target, and this target will call and execute `GenerateFileManifest` task.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing?view=vs-2019#example-2) and we can better understand `what the task means and what it really does for us during build process`. **To execute the GenerateFileManifest task actually is similar to call the method from GenerateFileManifest class**. And according to `FileItems="xxx" FileManifest="xxx" NgenLocalized="xxx"` these three input parameters,  this `GenerateFileManifest` class should have three **public property**. (While it actually doesn't have public property NgenLocalized defined in GenerateFileManifest class)

Then another line in `Microsoft.VsSDK.targets` file indicates this class from assembly `$(VsSDKCommonAssemblyFile)`, it's actually `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sdk.BuildTasks.dll` in the same folder. (`C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\microsoft.vssdk.buildtools\16.3.2093\tools\VSSDK\`)

```
<UsingTask TaskName="FindVsixManifest" AssemblyFile="$(VsSDKCommonAssemblyFile)" />
```

After view the structure of this assembly, I can't find the expected **NgenLocalized** public property. So it's the original cause of the issue in my opinion.

[image]

**Suggestions:**

1. If this issue can be reproduced in simple vsix project, feel free to report this issue
   by Help=>Send feedback=>Report the problem to report to Developer Community.
2. I think this issue comes from the 16.3.2093 package, the `Microsoft.VsSDK.targets` is not compatible perfectly with the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sdk.BuildTasks.dll`. So I think you can use previous version of this package.([16.2.3073](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools/16.2.3073) or earlier, in my machine I use 16.1.3132 version actually and it works well)

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Fantastic Lance, you have been such a help to me. I am still getting a runtime problem, but (if I can't fix it) I will make it a separate question.